# Format time from Rails to Swift - iOS

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, swift

I am trying to take the string returned by Rails created_at time-stamp and turn it into an `NSDate` that I can use in my Swift app. Here is what I have.

```
let rails_time = "2016-01-03 02:34:35 UTC"

let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"
let date_to = dateFormatter.dateFromString(rails_time)
```

This is returning `nil`. How do I get this to work?

Comment: Store datetime in string formate in your database not in datetime formate, then parse in ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `T` in your format string:

```
let rails_time = "2016-01-03 02:34:35 UTC"

let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz"
let date_to = dateFormatter.dateFromString(rails_time)
```